# Fire stick 4k - ADB hide updates (disable updates) permission error

Tags: android, adb, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

Im trying to turn off auto updates and I get this error.
Fire TC Stick 4k with the latest official updates.
Laptop is a MacOS with "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 30.0.0-6374843" from brew.

```
xx@mac ~> adb connect 192.168.111.111
already connected to 192.168.111.111:5555
xx@mac ~> adb shell pm hide com.amazon.device.software.ota
Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.
```

"Developer" options are all ON (ADB + Sources)

Answer (score 0):

its because of lack of permissions. You can grant by:

```
adb -d shell pm grant packageName android.permission.(permission name)
```